# How to center element in the div tag using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center an image in the `div` and I think made a mistake somewhere. This is my `html` and `css`:

```css
.col-xs-4 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid green;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <a class="col-xs-4" *ngFor="let products of categoryProduc; let i = index" [routerLink]="[products.name]">

    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ products.name }}</h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{ products.description }}</p>

    <img [src]="products.image" style="   left: 40%;
        max-height: 100px; ">
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to set `h2` and `p` on the center one under the other.

Comment: use the property `justify-content-center` . refer this bootstrap link for further details   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Comment: I add like that: 
   ` <img class="justify-content-center"
    [src]="products.image"
    style="   left: 40%;
    max-height: 100px; "        
>`, and this is no working

Comment: Since I see a `-xs-` column class is it safe to assume you're using a Bootstrap version < v4?If that's the case Sunny's solution won't apply and we'll sort you out another way.

Comment: i using version  `"version": "3.3.7"`

Comment: And I using ngx Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Just  use **text-center** a bootstrap class beside **row**. in parent div

Comment: It is good for `p`. But how center `button` and`img`? Ok, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

for single element put text center in class

> **( class="Text-Center")**

for row element

> **(class="row justify-content-center")**